# How to Remove day from date in python?

Tags: python

If I had a date in the format `'2016-07-31'`
How would I turn it to `'2016-07'`? I have datetime imported

Comment: for `day = '2016-07-31'`, you can simply do `day = day[:6]` to *cut* the string?

Comment: ^ won't work since its a datetime, and not a string

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `datetime`, you can parse the string with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and then use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to print just the parts you want:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> '{:%Y-%m}'.format(dt.strptime('2016-07-31', '%Y-%m-%d'))
'2016-07'
```

Although, as zeet points out, if you know your input will be of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD' it's simpler to just [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) it:

```
>>> date = '2016-07-31'
>>> date[:-3]
'2016-07'
>>> date[:date.rfind('-')]
'2016-07'
```

Still, using `strptime` will make it easier if you want to support more formats in a generic way.

Answer (score 4):

For example I get a column named as `df['column']` which has a list of values '2010-10-09' and moving on

**First Step:** turn this column data as type of `datetime` by using

```py
df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'])
```

**Second Step:** then change the style of this column by using

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

# %Y means year(full), four digits (e.g.2021).
# %y means year(short), only two digits (e.g.21).
# %m means month.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Update your question/answer to meet the standard of [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Finish the tour. Enjoy SO. End of Review.

Comment: this is a good answer, but just missed quotation marks. df['column'].dt.strftime( "%y-%m" )

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this, two ways are:

1. Assuming your dates are all constant width<sup>1</sup> (meaning each date has the same number of digits in it) you can simply do

   ```
   day = day[:6]
   ```
2. If your dates are *not* constant width then you can use `datetime` and you can simply do

   ```
   day = datetime.strptime(day, YOUR_FORMAT)
   day = day.strftime("%Y-%m")
   ```

You can piece together `YOUR_FORMAT` for your timestamps by looking at the [datetime reference here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Since your example shows a zero padded month it's pretty likely that you can go with option 1.

<sup>1</sup>You can actually get away with a non-constant width date provided that the year and month always come first and they *are* constant width.

Answer (score 0):

the format of "2016-07-31" is called ISO 8601 -format, 
this is what i recommend to do.

```
date_str = "2012-04-21"
wanted_format = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%Y-%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to substract current number of days from datetime object, then following code can help

```
from datetime import date, timedelta 
today = date.today() # datetime.date(2022, 5, 26)
result = today - timedelta(days=today.day) #  datetime.date(2022, 4, 30)
```